# Outbound Messaging

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

I need to create a outbound message service every time when a user make change in his/her first name. In order to solve this issue I planned to create a outbound message.

I created a outbound message setup successfully but unfortunately i am receiving some error. The error message is as following

I receive a Delivery Failure Reason stating

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that the end-point you are using (the target of your outbound Message) is https, but the certificate its used is either in-valid or not signed by a CA trusted by SalesForce.

This list might help: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates

Give it a try without https (just http) and see if it also complains. If it doesn't complain, then it is most likely an issue with the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This help me to solve the issue. I tried with http and everything work fine, So i am planning to get a new certificate that works with salesforce for my server and see will that one work.

Comment: If its for a personal server, you could also try _Let's Encrypt_ , but in my case I'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair` maybe you have more luck ;)